# Rails: PayPal Integration: "Load Configurations from specified file"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

I'm attempting to follow the steps at https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-ruby to create my first restful call.

I've already run "rails g paypal:sdk:install" to create the paypal.yml file. What does the next section "Load Configurations from specified file" mean? What am I supposed to do with this:

```
PayPal::SDK::Core::Config.load('spec/config/paypal.yml',  ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development')
```

?

Comment: Do I add that line to the paypal initializer? It currently has "PayPal::SDK.load("config/paypal.yml", Rails.env)
PayPal::SDK.logger = Rails.logger"

Comment: That's probably a bug in their README. If you look at some of their other gems, you'll see `PayPal::SDK.load('config/paypal.yml',  ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running a Rails app, `rails g paypal:sdk:install` should do the trick.

Here is the initializer `initializers/paypal.rb`:

```
PayPal::SDK.load("config/paypal.yml", Rails.env)
PayPal::SDK.logger = Rails.logger
```

[`PayPal::SDK.load`](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-ruby/blob/master/lib/paypal-sdk-core.rb#L25) in turn calls [`PayPal::SDK::Core::Config.load`](https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-ruby/blob/master/lib/paypal-sdk/core/config.rb#L159). You can skip that step.